# Creating sublists by rule

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to make a sublist consisting of the four elements that follow each occurrence of 1, 2 in the list:

```
lis = {a, b, 1, 2, c, d, e, f, g, 1, 2, w, x, y , z, q, r}
```

to make:

```
res = {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}
```

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Cases[{2, p__} /; Length[{p}] >= 4 :> {p}[[;; 4]]] @ 
  Rest @ Split[lis, {#, #2} =!= {1, 2} &]
```

> ```
> {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}
> ```

And a variation:

```
Cases[{2, p__} /; Length[{p}] >= 4 :> Take[{p}, 4]] @ 
  Rest @ Split[lis, {#, #2} =!= {1, 2} &]
```

> ```
> {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}
> ```

Comment: +1, but both solutions will fail in the cases like `lis = {2, a, b, f, h, 1, 2, c, d, e, f};`.

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyPopkov; good catch. Looks like wrapping `Split` with `Rest` fixes the issue.

Comment: Good idea with `Rest`! Probably more efficient version: `Cases[{2, p : Repeated[_, {4}], ___} :> {p}]@Rest@Split[lis, {#, #2} =!= {1, 2} &]`.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
res = #[[-4 ;;]] & /@ SequenceCases[lis, {1, 2, _, _, _, _}]
(*{{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}*)
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution to @TumbiSapichu's one:

```
SequenceCases[lis, {1, 2, p : Repeated[_, {4}]} :> {p}]
(* {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(lis // SequencePosition[#,{1,2}][[All,2]]& // {1 + #,4 + #}&// Transpose) 
// Map[Take[lis,#]&]

(* {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}} * )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lis[[# + 1 ;; # + 4]] & /@ (#[[2]] & /@ SequencePosition[lis, {1, 2}])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Partition` can assist in generating lists that have the correct length and need subsequent filtering only.

```
lis = {a, b, 1, 2, c, d, e, f, g, 1, 2, w, x, y, z, q, r};

Cases[Partition[lis, 6, 1], {1, 2, a__} :> {a}]
```

> {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}

Consider a list (`lis2`) with an overlap and less than 4 characters after `1,2`.

```
lis2 = {a, b, 1, 2, c, d, e, f, g, 1, 2, w, x, y, z, q, r, a, b, 1, 2, c, d, g, 1, 2, k, l, m, n, q, r};

Cases[Partition[lis2, 6, 1], {1, 2, a__} :> {a}]
```

> {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}, {c, d, g, 1}, {k, l, m, n}}

The third sublist can be filtered with an improved pattern that removes the overlap, if required.

```
Cases[Partition[lis2, 6, 1]
 , {1, 2, b__ /; FreeQ[{b}, 1 | 2]} :> {b}]
```

> {{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}, {k, l, m, n}}

Comment: (+1) Nice, @Syed!

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Cases` and `SequenceSplit`:

```
Cases[SequenceSplit[lis, Repeated[{1, 2}]], x_ /; Length[x] >= 4 :> x[[1 ;; 4]]]

{{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {a, b, 1, 2, c, d, e, f, g, 1, 2, w, x, y, z, q, r};
```

A variant of 1066's answer:

```
Take[list, #] & /@
 Replace[SequencePosition[list, {1, 2}], {_, a_} :> {a + 1, a + 4}, {1}]
```

{{c, d, e, f}, {w, x, y, z}}